# Drools decision table and app no interaction

Tags: java, drools

My simple app works fine with `.drl`, but I wanted to check it with decision tables. Unfortunately, no tweaking and reading resolved the problem. I read that decision tables are not suitable to all kinds of tasks – are they in my case?

```
public static class UserInfo {

    public enum Category {
        var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5
    }

    public enum Degree {
        high, medium, low;
    }
}
```

My `.drl` looks like this:

```
item : UserInfo( variable_n == UserInfo.Category.var_1 , 
      level_n == UserInfo.Degree.high) and 
      item2 : UserInfo( variable_n == UserInfo.Category.var_2 ,
      level_n == UserInfo.Degree.high) etc...
```

The shortened decision table:

[image: Shortened decision table (var_1 - var_5)].

Comment: I've edited your post to be more clear. "Not working" is never a good description of a problem; maybe [edit] your post to say what you expected to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: @BenjaminW. thank you for editing!

Comment: AS far as I can see, your decision table produces a constraint `item:UserInfo(Category.variable_n == var_1)` which won't be what you have in your DRL and is syntactically wrong. The cells below ìtem:UserInfo` should be `variable_n` and `UserInfo.Category.var_1`.  (I don't see how you could come up with `Category.variable_n`, which is far from any plausible Jave expression.)

Comment: @laune thank you for your advice! yes, i have already tried before they way how you say, but still no results. You mean that UserInfo class is well designed?

Comment: What I see of class UserInfo shouldn't create any problems (except that those enum identifiers are lengthier than necessary). - "No results" could be due to any number of reasons. Have you looked at the generated DRL code? Did you check that DRL compiling does not produce any errors?